# negative forcasts using facebook prophet

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, forecasting, arima, facebook-prophet

I  have a daily time series  data  for   almost 2 years   for cluster  available space (in GB). I  am trying to   to use  facebook's prophet to do future forecasts. Some forecasts  have   negative values. Since   negative values  does not make   sense I saw that  using carrying capacity   for logistic growth model   helps   in  eliminating negative  forecasts  with  cap   values. I am not sure   if this   is applicable for this case and how  to get the  cap value    for my time series. Please help  as I am new to this  and  confused. I am  using Python 3.6

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import openpyxl
from pandas import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
from fbprophet import Prophet
import os
import sys
import signal




df = pd.read_excel("Data_Per_day.xlsx")
df1=df.filter(['cluster_guid','date','avail_capacity'],axis=1)
uniquevalues = np.unique(df1[['cluster_guid']].values)

for id in uniquevalues:


newdf = df1[df1['cluster_guid'] == id]

    newdf1=newdf.groupby(['cluster_guid','date'],as_index=False['avail_capacity'].sum()
        #newdf11=newdf.groupby(['cluster_guid','date'],as_index=False)['total_capacity'].sum()
        #cap[id]=newdf11['total_capacity'].max()
        #print(cap[id])
    newdf1.set_index('cluster_guid', inplace=True)

    newdf1.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a',header=None)
with open('my_csv.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data = [line for line in r]
with open('my_csv.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['cluster_guid','DATE_TAKEN','avail_capacity'])
    w.writerows(data)





in_df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='DATE_TAKEN' )

in_df.to_csv('my_csv.csv')

dfs= pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv')
uni=dfs.cluster_guid.unique()

while True:
    try:
        print(" Press Ctrl +C  to exit   or  enter the cluster guid to be forcasted")
        i=input('Please enter the cluster  guid')
        if i not in uni:
            print( 'Please  enter a  valid cluster  guid')
            continue
        else:

        dfs1=dfs.loc[df['cluster_guid'] == i]
        dfs1.drop('cluster_guid', axis=1, inplace=True)
        dfs1.to_csv('dataframe'+i+'.csv', index=False)
        dfs2=pd.read_csv('dataframe'+i+'.csv')
        dfs2['DATE_TAKEN'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dfs2['DATE_TAKEN'])
        dfs2 = dfs2.rename(columns={'DATE_TAKEN': 'ds','avail_capacity': 'y'})
        my_model = Prophet(interval_width=0.99)
        my_model.fit(dfs2)
        future_dates = my_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=30, freq='D')
        forecast = my_model.predict(future_dates)
        print(forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']])
        my_model.plot(forecast,uncertainty=True)
        my_model.plot_components(forecast)
        plt.show()

        os.remove('dataframe'+i+'.csv')
        os.remove('my_csv.csv')


except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    try:
        os.remove('my_csv.csv')
    except OSError:
        pass
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you add some code you have written so far.

Comment: Please  find the  code so far

Answer (score 4):

Box-Cox transform of order 0 get the trick done. Here are the steps:

```
1. Add 1 to each values (so as to avoid log(0))
2. Take natural log of each value
3. Make forecasts
4. Take exponent and subtract 1
```

This way you will not get negative forecasts. Also log have a nice property of converting multiplicative seasonality to additive form.